# Building glut with Makefile in mac OSX

Tags: macos, makefile, linker, glut

completely Makefile newbie here. I was asked by a professor to submit a Makefile along with the actual source code. I'm having a hard time getting the linker to find the Glut files.
My application has the following structure

[image: app structure]

My main.cpp has the following dependencies:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "renderer.cpp"
```

My renderer.cpp has the following dependencies:

```
#define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "reader.cpp"
#include "../../../Common/Point.h"
```

My reader.cpp has the following dependencies:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "../headers/reader.h"
#include "../../../Common/Point.h"
```

And finally my Point.cpp has the following dependencies:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "Point.h"
```

I have zero experience with Makefile, and all i know was taken from a youtube video i watch to have a base of what to do. The Makefile goes as follows:

```
engine: main.o renderer.o reader.o Point.o
        g++ main.o renderer.o reader.o Point.o -o engine

main.o: main.cpp
        g++ -c main.cpp $ ./renderer.cpp $(-framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -framework      Cocoa)

renderer.o: renderer.cpp
            g++ -c renderer.cpp $(-framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa) $   ./reader.cpp $ ../../../Common/Point.h

reader.o: reader.cpp
      g++ -c reader.cpp $ ../headers/reader.h $ ../../../Common/Point.h

Point.o: ../../../Common/Point.cpp
     g++ -c ../../../Common/Point.cpp $ ../../../Common/Point.h

clean:
    rm *.o
    rm *.xml
    rm *.3d
```

When i try to run the make, i get the error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:" followed by every glut/Opengl function i call.
I know the makefile is completely bad written but i would really appreciate some help.

Comment: What are all those `$` values in your makefile recipes?  They seem quite useless.  The problem, no doubt, is the `$(-framework ...)` stuff.  That is basically trying to expand a make variable names `-framework GLUT -framework OpenGL ...` which doesn't exist, so it expands to the empty string.

Comment: The most important thing when debugging a makefile is to look at the compiler command that make prints out, and make sure it's right.  If it's not right, you need to examine your recipe to figure out why.  In order to know why, you need to know what the right command should be.  If you can run the command at the shell prompt and have it do what you want, then it's trivial to turn that into a makefile.  If you don't know how to run it from the shell prompt, you'll never be able to write a makefile to do it.